# Send e-mail with Intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

i have a problem with XDK.I'm trying to send an email but i don't know what is wrong. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function notEmpty(){
        var myTextField = document.getElementById('Name').value,document.getElementById('Mail').value;

        if(myTextField.value != ""){
            intel.xdk.device.sendEmail(myTextField.value, 'mail@mail.comr', 'Contact', true, null, null)
        }else{
            alert("Would you please enter some text?") 
        }
    }
</script>

...
<input class="wide-control" placeholder="Placeholder Text" type="text" id="Nome">
</div>
<div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="1">
    <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="Mail">Input</label>
    <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Placeholder Text" type="text" id="Mail">
</div>

<a class="button widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="1">Button</a>
<button onclick="notEmpty()">Click me</button>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Intel XDK's SendEmail method: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493039

This will open the phone's native e-mail application with the parameters you provide prepopulated. For this to work, you must have the "email" options checked in the build settings for Cordova Plugin. You also need to be testing the compiled application Intel XDK provides after the build process.

This feature IS NOT observable when testing in the "emulator" or in a browser. The Javascript API needs to hook into native phone functionality to work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Helped me a lot.

Comment: A last doubt:  This feature IS NOT observable when testing in the "emulator" or in a browser.   How i can test my code?

Comment: It can be a pain to get your first iOS application to build, but it's relatively painless to build your first Android application. You would have to select the "Build" tab, build for android, upload project, etc. Then download and install the app on your phone.

If you have the correct permissions enabled, that click event should open Android's native e-mail application with your parameters. This "may" work when using "AppPreview" and the "Test" tab, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You might have luck with the Debug tab and a usb-connected device.  With the latest release (2496) it includes the ability to work with third party plugins.  It has to build a container in which it runs so it can take a while the first time you start it, but it caches it so as long as you don't change your plugins it won't have to rebuild it.